# Using bash to plot a graph

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have a huge file  which contains BGP updates in the following fashion :

```
BGP4MP|1043481872|A|64.200.199.3|7911|217.72.176.0/20|7911 8272 16102 16102 16102|IGP|64.200.199.3|0|0|7911:999 7911:7211|NAG||
```

Basically, it is derived from using the `route_btoa` function.

I want to plot a graph based on the 2nd and 3rd fields of this line (you can ignore everything else). The 2nd field indicates time and the third field indicates if it is an Announcement (A) or Withdrawal (W) - these are the only two cases.

The graph is supposed to have as X-axis the time and Y-axis will be the number of BGP (A) - we ignore W-  updates at that time. 
If anyone could help me plot this, that would be a great help! Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an un-editable version of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/274575/117549