# Plotting graphs using bash

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have a file in the following format:

```
1043481872
1043481872
1043481872
1043481872
1043481873
1043481873
1043481873
1043481873
1043481874
1043481874
1043481874
1043481875
```

My question now boils down to a simple graph where the X axis is the unique values in the table and the Y axis would be the number of values of each of them. Eg 1043481874 would be x axis and 3 would be Y axis. If anyone could tell me how to write a bash script to plot this, it would be very helpful

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034257/plot-number-of-requests-per-minute-from-timestamp-csv and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256598/parsing-timestamp-with-value-and-plot-by-gnuplot for solutions to similar questions.  and this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-handle-time-based-data-with-gnuplot/

Answer (score 2):

Use `uniq -c` to generate the counts from your file:

```
4 1043481872
4 1043481873
3 1043481874
1 1043481875
```

Plot the datapoints with `gnuplot`; the relevant `plot` statement in the `gnuplot` configuration would include

```
plot … using 2:1
```

to transpose the X/Y order of the output from `uniq`.